# Intrinsic polarity of a currentless coil

Tags: electromagnetism

How is polarity of a coil without current determined? Is there a convention for right handed coil being North at top and vice versa in a helically wound coil ?

According to Faraday's Law sign of EMF is decided by the relative sign of velocity between coil and permanent magnet no matter the coil is wound right handed or left handed.. or even of both handed sign on each half of a single coil... is that correct?

In other words there is no such thing as geometrical polarity of an inert helical wound coil and the right and left handedness of current by Laws of Faraday/Lenz  are not related to it, right?

There ought to be no [Coil Polarity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HyORmBip-w) marked in so many places, books? like from 37 secs. on the video? Should n't what I marked N-S in my picture is also incorrect?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a convention for right handed coil being North at top and vice versa in a helically wound coil ?

No, there can't be such a convention, because how would we determine which end of the two is the "top" one? For a coil with single chirality, say left-handed one, both coil ends have the same chirality, so they're equivalent.

> or even of both handed sign on each half of a single coil... is that correct?

Yes.

> there is no such thing as geometrical polarity of an inert helical wound coil and the right and left handedness of current by Laws of Farady/Lenz are not related to it, right?

Right. However, induced current in the coil and other coils nearby may depend on whether the coil is left-handed or right-handed. For example, the Tesla transformer works well only for some combination of chiralities of primary and secondary coil; if you take the primary and rewind it to have the opposite chirality, the transformer won't work.

Comment: Does the labelling $N-S$ then make sense